# Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open './.babelrc'

Tags: node.js, reactjs, core-js

I am new to react and node ENV. Trying to build an app and it throws error, even though the DIR contains the babel.rc file. Still couldn't find it for some reason, I am attaching a similar post for reference but couldn't fix it. Any help is deeply appreciated.

Thank you :)

https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/7906

Comment: You say the directory contains `babel.rc` but the binary is looking for `.babelrc` - are you sure you've named the file correctly? A cursory search led me [to this page in the babel docs](https://babeljs.io/docs/en/configuration) which suggests that you use `config.babel.json` or `.babelrc.json` depending on how you want to structure the configuration

Comment: @CarsonMyers so sorry I meant to add this link https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/7906 and thanks for the help. That link has the similar issue I am facing

Comment: Did you try the [solution mentioned in this comment](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/7906#issuecomment-229030093) under that github issue?

Comment: @CarsonMyers

I couldn't find that specific location mentioned in the comment "@mschipperheyn Try resetting the packager's cache:

./node_modules/react-native/packager/packager.sh start --reset-cache

Also bear in mind that react-native's transform picks up .babelrc in parent-directories like your home-folder as well." 

I don't see this file react-native/packager/packager.sh start --reset-cache